# Using Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient to get all office 365 users mail folders

Tags: uwp, microsoft-graph-api

I am writing a UWP program that uses MS Graph to get users mail folders and then messages.

I acquire an access token using my credentials while I am admin in Azure AD and Office 365.
calling this with my id = my alias it is working right.
                var mailFoldersPage = await graphClient.Users[id].MailFolders.Request().GetAsync();

But calling it while id = someone else alias give me MS Graph ServiceException 
Code: ErrorAccessDenied
Message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.

Can someone help me out?

thanks
Mohamed Hassanin

Answer (score 0):

[Delegated Mail permissions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#mail-permissions) do not provide access another user's mailbox unless it has been explicitly shared with your account.

In order to access any user's mailbox, you would need to use [Application Mail permissions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#application-permissions-9). These are acquired using the [Client Credentials grant](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service).

Comment: This is what I had ended up doing and it works great. But I couldn't able to do it in WUP so I had to do it in WPF program.